# Finding Driving/Walking distance between 2 locations in Swift 3 using Google Maps API

Tags: swift, google-maps, swift3

I am trying to get the driving/walking distance between two locations using the Google Maps API. I am updating my app to Swift 3, from objective-c and right now I'm stuck on converting this block of code to Swift 3.

```
NSString *dist;
NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=false&mode=%@", closestLocation.coordinate.latitude,  closestLocation.coordinate.longitude, _currentUserLocation.coordinate.latitude,  _currentUserLocation.coordinate.longitude, @"DRIVING"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[strUrl stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if(jsonData != nil)
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSMutableArray *arrDistance=[result objectForKey:@"routes"];
    if ([arrDistance count]==0) {
        NSLog(@"N.A.");
    }
    else{
        NSMutableArray *arrLeg=[[arrDistance objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"legs"];
        NSMutableDictionary *dictleg=[arrLeg objectAtIndex:0];

        dist = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[dictleg   objectForKey:@"distance"] objectForKey:@"text"]];
    }
}
else{
    NSLog(@"N.A.");
}
```

I tried using tools like Swiftify, but keep getting errors everywhere. What I have right now is:

```
var dist: String = ""
var strUrl: String = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(closestLocation!.coordinate.latitude),\(closestLocation!.coordinate.longitude)&destination=\(currentUserLocation!.coordinate.latitude),\(currentUserLocation!.coordinate.longitude)&sensor=false&mode=\("DRIVING")"
var url = URL(string: strUrl)
var jsonData = Data(contentsOf: url!)
    if (jsonData != nil) {
        var error: Error? = nil
        var result: Any? = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.Element.mutableContainers)
        var arrDistance: [Any]? = (result?["routes"] as? [Any])
        if arrDistance?.count == 0 {
            print("N.A.")
        }
        else {
            var arrLeg: [Any]? = ((arrDistance?[0] as? [Any])?["legs"] as? [Any])
            var dictleg: [AnyHashable: Any]? = (arrLeg?[0] as? [AnyHashable: Any])

            dist = "\(dictleg?["distance"]["text"])"
        }
    }
    else {
        print("N.A.")
    }
```

My errors now are the following:

with the Data(contentsOf: url!) it tells me "Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

And it doesn't like how I use [Any] for my arrDistance variable.

If anyone knows how to implement this API call in Swift 3, it would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Not related to the question but you should't use  Data(contentsOf: url!) to download data. You should use URLSession `dataTask(with: URL)`

Comment: But why are you using Google's API and not Apple's internal one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What compiler is saying that [`Data(contentsOf:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/1779617-init) will `throws` exception so that you need to handle it with `do catch` block. Now as suggested in comment you need to use [`dataTask(with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask) instead of `Data(contentsOf:)` to download data. Also you can make completion block with your code, so make changes in your code like below.

```
func getDistance(completion: @escaping(String) -> Void) {

    var dist = ""
    let strUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(closestLocation!.coordinate.latitude),\(closestLocation!.coordinate.longitude)&destination=\(currentUserLocation!.coordinate.latitude),\(currentUserLocation!.coordinate.longitude)&sensor=false&mode=\("DRIVING")"
    let url = URL(string: strUrl)!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            completion(dist)
            return
        }
        if let result = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as? [String:Any],
            let routes = result["routes"] as? [[String:Any]], let route = routes.first,
            let legs = route["legs"] as? [[String:Any]], let leg = legs.first,
            let distance = leg["distance"] as? [String:Any], let distanceText = distance["text"] as? String {

            dist = distanceText
        }
        completion(dist)
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Now simply call `getDistance` function like this way.

```
self.getDistance { (distance) in
    //Update UI on main thread
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print(distance)
        self.label.text = distance
    }
}
```

Comment: But then I run into the problem with not being able to store the value of that distance variable. I'm trying to put that value on a label on one of my view controllers

Comment: @trludt Don't you simply set label text instead of `print` statement in completion of `getDistance` like `self.getDistance { (distance) in
    yourLabel.text = distance
}`

Comment: It takes a while for the labels to show up with the value. It technically works, but I need that information to show up as soon as the view loads.

Comment: @trludt The completion block call depends upon your net speed but if you are getting response and still it is taking time to update UI than make UI changes on main thread so put your UI changes code inside `DispatchQueue.main.async { //Make ui changes here }`

Comment: so I put the self.getDistance functions inside the DispatchQueue.main.async { } and updated the UI through there and it still takes almost 20-30 seconds to update.

Comment: @trludt No not put the `self.getDistance` inside main thread check my edited answer and call ui changes on main thread

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5+:**
If anyone looking for answers uses CoreLocation.
As far as I know, there are two ways to find the distance.
If you are looking for driving distance, you can always use MKDirections.
Here is the code for finding driving distance (You can also find walking, and transit distance by changing transport type).

```
let sourceP = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( sourceLat, sourceLong)
let destP = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( desLat, desLong)
let source = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceP)
let destination = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destP)
        
let request = MKDirections.Request()
request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: source)
request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destination)

// Specify the transportation type
request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.automobile;

// If you want only the shortest route, set this to a false
request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true

let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

 // Now we have the routes, we can calculate the distance using
 directions.calculate { (response, error) in
    if let response = response, let route = response.routes.first {
                print(route.distance) //This will return distance in meters
    }
 }
```

If you are only looking for air distance/bird's eye distance/coordinate distance, you can use this code:

```
let sourceP = CLLocation(latitude: sourceLat, longitude: sourceLong)
let desP = CLLocation(latitude: desLat, longitude: desLong))

let distanceInMeter = sourceP.distance(from: desP)
```